# Capture error response from Firebase.auth() for display to user

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, firebase-authentication

I'm using React Native/Firebase/Redux to build a simple login system. I am trying to work out how to capture errors that happen as a result of failed login attempts.

Here's my authscreen.js:

```
const [alertShowing, setAlertShowing] = useState(false);
const [alertMessage, setAlertMessage] = useState('');
...

  function handleLogin() {
    const response = dispatch(login(email, password));
    console.log(response);
  }
```

actions.js:

```
export const login = (email, password) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const response = await Firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      dispatch(getUser(response.user.uid));
    } catch (e) {
        return e;
    }
  };
};
```

My console.log(response) above correctly shows me the error message, but this obviously isn't very useful to users. And please note too that I can log in properly when using correct credentials.

What I really want to do in my `handleLogin()` is check if the response is an error, and if so, `setlAlertShowing(true)` and `setAlertMessage` to what I've gotten back from the useDispatch hook so that I may display it nicely to the user.

How should I go about this? TIA.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firebase errors messages are designed for developers and not standard users friendly. The solution is to identify authentication error code and map with user-friendly messages.

list of error code https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors

You can use function like this to map authError to meaningful error messages.

```js
function mapAuthCodeToMessage(authCode) {
  switch (authCode) {
    case "auth/invalid-password":
      return "Password provided is not corrected";

    case "auth/invalid-email":
      return "Email provided is invalid";

    // Many more authCode mapping here...

    default:
      return "";
  }
}
```

and use it later

```js
export const login = (email, password) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const response = await Firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      dispatch(getUser(response.user.uid));
    } catch (e) {
        dispatch({type:"authError",message:mapAuthCodeToMessage(e.code)}));

    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks.